# modules expose imported packages

Tags: python, module

I have a module:

```
test
   __init__.py
```

In `__init__.py` I have single line:

```
import numpy as np
```

I want to use numpy across the package (modules and submodules) I want to create.

Problem is, somehow numpy is getting exposed. If I run IPython and do

```
import test
```

There will be a test.np accessible.

I looked at many packages on github and they often import a lot in the main `__init__.py` (sys, division, etc) and yet when I import those packages in IPython none of the external modules are exposed.

What are they doing differently?

Comment: Since you're looking at the sources of these packages, perhaps you can see what they're doing that prevents it.

Comment: yes, looking into this, but no idea thus far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a global name `__all__`, set to a list or tuple of names, to limit what is imported and what documentation tools *generally* will list:

```
__all__ = ['function1', 'ClassName2']
```

The `__all__` name limits what `from test import *` will import, and is also used by documentation tools to limit what is listed as public API for a given module.

See the [`import` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html) documentation:

> The *public names* defined by a module are determined by checking the module’s namespace for a variable named `__all__`; if defined, it must be a sequence of strings which are names defined or imported by that module. The names given in `__all__` are all considered public and are required to exist. If `__all__` is not defined, the set of public names includes all names found in the module’s namespace which do not begin with an underscore character (`'_'`). `__all__` should contain the entire public API. It is intended to avoid accidentally exporting items that are not part of the API (such as library modules which were imported and used within the module).

The `__init__` modules you inspected will almost certainly define `__all__` sequences.

You can also *delete* names again from your module, provided your functions do not need access to the global names later:

```
del sys
```

The IPython autocompletion otherwise uses *all* names that do not start with an underscore; the autocompletion ignores the `__all__` list, but will ignore names like `_sys`.

The [`numpy.__init__` module](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.7.x/numpy/__init__.py) (before version 1.8.0) itself deletes names from the global namespace again:

```
if __NUMPY_SETUP__:
    import sys as _sys
    _sys.stderr.write('Running from numpy source directory.\n')
    del _sys
```

but here `sys` is bound as `_sys` and IPython would ignore that name even if it wasn't deleted. `numpy` also builds up an `__all__` list in that module.

In `numpy` version 1.8.0 and newer, a `import sys` statement was added to that file and IPython offers it for autocompletion, because it is still part of the global namespace.

Comment: Using `__all__` and leaving out `np` won't make `test.np` inaccessible.

Comment: @martineau: No, but *that is not the question*. IPython shows auto-completion targets, and the OP is wondering why some projects seem to import all sorts of libraries but IPython is not listing them.

Comment: I tested this and even if I have `__all__` = [] I still see in IPython everything I import in `__init__.py`. Regardless whether the import statement is import numpy or import numpy as np, import sys etc.

Comment: @dreamwalker: Did you restart IPython or reload the module? The module is imported just once and not automatically re-loaded.

Comment: I restart it every time I make changes to the module.

Comment: @dreamwalker: can you name a library where you *don't* see everything in it listed?

Comment: `__init__.py` for numpy imports sys and warnings for example. When I run IPython I don't see them and also I can't do numpy.sys ('module' object has no attribute 'sys') I can however do numpy.warnings

Comment: @dreamwalker: I may be wrong about IPython heeding `__all__` for autocompletion; I'm testing this again now. It should certainly use `__all__` for documentation (`help(testing)`). `numpy` *deletes* names again from the `__init__`.

Comment: @dreamwalker: see [this line](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/__init__.py#L141); `sys` is imported as `_sys` as well, but it is also deleted again with `del _sys`.

Comment: @alko: indeed it is. Intriguing. And curious why the file then reimports `sys` as `_sys` to do the warning.

Comment: @alko: using 1.8.0 IPython *does* offer `sys` as an auto-completion target.

Comment: @alko: So your point is that things numpy `__init__.py` imports that aren't deleted are accessible -- so the OP is wrong?

Comment: @martineau: The OP is using a version before 1.8.0.

Comment: thank you very much for all your help, this sheds much more light on the situation, guess I need to read up a bit more on how to organize modules and also I seem to be wanting to break up things into too many files where I guess in the Python world it doesn't make sense...

Answer (score -1):

You have to make sure you are only importing it into the local namespace somehow.

Comment: While this could be done by importing it into each module function that uses it, besides being tedious it would also be inefficient.