# defining package level path constants

Tags: python, import, package

I frequently find I'd like to define constants at the package level, mostly for defining paths that are above modules in the filesystem hierarchy.  I have the following method:

director structure:

```
my_project
    tests
    examples
    data
    my_package
        __init__.py
        mod1.py
        mod2.py
        ...
```

contents of `my_project/my_package/__init__.py`:

```py
import my_package
import os

__package_path = os.path.split(my_package.__path__[0])[0]
TESTS_FOLDER = os.path.join(__package_path, 'tests')
EXAMPLES_FOLDER = os.path.join(__package_path, 'examples')
DATA_FOLDER = os.path.join(__package_path, 'local')
```

This allows for, e.g.:

```py
import my_package
my_package.TESTS_FOLDER #returns path for tests
```

As a solution to getting the file paths of modules or project files, this seems quite nice - there is a lot of discussion/confusion over how to get valid paths of a script ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-do-i-get-the-full-path-of-the-current-files-directory) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-to-properly-determine-current-script-directory) for example).  My question: will import `my_package` within its own `__init__.py` result in unusual/undesired behavior? or: what is the idiomatic way to define package level constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks generally accepted, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989179/modules-expose-imported-packages) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python). Here is an improved version of `__init__.py`:

```
import my_package
import os

__package_path = os.path.split(my_package.__path__[0])[0]
TESTS_FOLDER = os.path.join(__package_path, 'tests')
EXAMPLES_FOLDER = os.path.join(__package_path, 'examples')
DATA_FOLDER = os.path.join(__package_path, 'local')

del my_package
del os
del __package_path
```

The `del` statements prevents unwanted variables from being exposed in the `my_package` namespace, so you can't do weird things like this:

```
import my_namespace
print(my_namespace.my_namespace.my_namespace.TESTS_FOLDER)
```

Elsewhere, the line `__all__ = ["TESTS_FOLDER", "EXAMPLES_FOLDER", "DATA_FOLDER"]` is sometimes used, but this will only work for the specific import structure `from my_namespace import *`.  For that reason, the `del` method appears preferable.